# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain Fails With E_ACCESSDENIED When Using Same HWND

Tags: c++, directx

If I create a window and pass the HWND to D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, it works. However, after I release the device, context, swapchain, etc and try to repeat the process using the same HWND, D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain fails with E_ACCESSDENIED. This tells me something must be holding onto the HWND, but what? I release all my global variables in the destructor of the class. Anyone have an idea what the problem is?

```
~decoder()
    {
        m_VertexShader->Release();
        m_VertexShader = nullptr;

        m_PixelShader->Release();
        m_PixelShader = nullptr;

        m_InputLayout->Release();
        m_InputLayout = nullptr;

        device->Release();
        device = nullptr;

        context->Release();
        context = nullptr;

        swapchain->Release();
        swapchain = nullptr;

        rendertargetview->Release();
        rendertargetview = nullptr;

        m_SamplerLinear->Release();
        m_SamplerLinear = nullptr;

        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        hr = decoder_transform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_END_OF_STREAM, NULL);
        hr = decoder_transform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_END_STREAMING, NULL);
        hr = decoder_transform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL);

        decoder_transform.Release();
        color_transform.Release();

        hr = MFShutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post this as the solution so I can accept it? After releasing m_SamplerLinear I added context->ClearState() and context->Flush() and moved the context->Release() after that which fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [`D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-d3d11createdeviceandswapchain) does not mention why this is happening in the documentation, it is essentially just a wrapper around creating a `D3D11Device` and swap chain. The documentation for [IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforhwnd#remarks) does go into detail on why this is happening.

> Because you can associate only one flip presentation model swap chain at a time with an HWND, the Microsoft Direct3D 11 policy of deferring the destruction of objects can cause problems if you attempt to destroy a flip presentation model swap chain and replace it with another swap chain. For more info about this situation, see [Deferred Destruction Issues with Flip Presentation Swap Chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-flush#remarks).

The documentation regarding [Deferred Destruction Issues with Flip Presentation Swap Chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-flush#remarks) advises calling [`ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-clearstate) followed by [`ID3D11DeviceContext::Flush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-flush).

> However, if an application must actually destroy an old swap chain and create a new swap chain, the application must force the destruction of all objects that the application freed. To force the destruction, call ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearState (or otherwise ensure no views are bound to pipeline state), and then call Flush on the immediate context. You must force destruction before you call IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd, IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow, or IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition again to create a new swap chain.

Comment: See also https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/